# SIMULINK use signal that will act as a bus input

Tags: input, simulink, bus

I have a SIMULINK model that uses bus inputs and outputs as top level ports. When I am testing it, I don't know how to create a test signal as a bus and feed it into the model. I know that the straightforward way to do it is to create lots of individual signal and use `bus creator` block to group those as a bus that will feed into the model. However, this may not be a very efficient way to do things. Does anyone know any alternative?

I tried to look into Mathworks website but nothing really came up. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your test signal is constant the easiest way is to add a `Simulink` `Constant` block and define the variable as a structure in some script .m file:

```
testSignal.a = 10;
testSignal.b = 20;
etc
```

Double-click on the `Constant` block, add the variable and then switch to the `Signal Attributes` tab where you specify the data type to match your bus signal definition.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the data using Timeseries objects.  See [Import Structure of timeseries Objects for Buses](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/importing-structures-of-matlab-timeseries-objects-for-bus-signals-to-a-root-level-input-port.html)

for an example.

Comment: Thanks for this! I just wanted to point it out that this solution probably doesn't work for legacy versions (before R2012 or R2011) as Mathworks didn't have those necessary classdefs.